# Issue Installing ninja-build for centos 7

Tags: linux, installation, centos, ninja

I can successfully build `ninja` locally in `~/programs` in CentOS7 using the following set of commands:

```
mkdir -p programs
cd programs

git clone https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git
cd ninja
git checkout release
./configure.py --bootstrap

./ninja --version
1.11.1
```

However, I am trying to install it system-wide but it is only recognizable in `~/programs/ninja`. Shouldn't `./configure.py --bootstrap` install it automatically?

How can I install it in `/usr/bin/ninja`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After build ninja move it to /usr/bin

```
mv ./ninja /usr/bin
```